# Javascript function acting like object and function

Tags: javascript

By API design I need something like this:

```
Store = function(fn, args) {
     return this[fn](args); 
}
Store.getOptions() { return this.options}
Store.setLog(args) { this.options.log = args}
```

Create objects instances from Store with separate options, Ex:

```
option1 = {save:false, log: true}
Store1 = new -->  Store(option1)  //pseudo code object creation

let opt1 = Store1('getOptions');   //Store acting like a function

Store1('setLogs', false);          //same call
Store1.setLogs(false);
```

Store act like a object(create new objects) and can be called.

I was trying with Store.bind(options) but defined properties `getOptions` and `setLog` get lost it.

Answer (score 1):

Which EcmaScript version are you targeting: EcmaScript 5 or EcmaScript 6 (EcmaScript 2015)?

**EcmaScript 5 class creation:**

```
// Declare constructor for class Store:
var Store = function(){ /* This code will be executed when you call 'new Store()' */ };
```

**NOTE**: All properties and functions for instances of class are added to prototype property of class constructor function. */

```
// Add properties for each instance of class Store:
Store.prototype.options = {Hi:'World'}; // Each instance of Store will have object with property Hi:'World'

// Add functions for each instance of class Store:
Store.prototype.SayHello = function(name){
    console.log('Hello ', name);
};
```

Usage:

```
var store1 = new Store();
store1.SayHello('Phillip'); //Will output: Hello Phillip
```

**EcmaScript 6 (EcmaScript 2015)**

Take a look to article about classes usage in [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever do?

```
let opt1 = Store1('getOptions');   //Store acting like a function
Store1('setLogs', false);          //same call
```

Just define the methods or compose them..

I can observe that you have 2 different use cases here:

1. Getting/setting options
2. Getting/setting log related stuff?

So why not:

```
var optionsProto = function() {
  var options = [];

  var getOption = function getOption(key) {
    if(options[key]) {
      return options[key];
    }

    //Handle error or return undefined..
  };

  var setOption = function setOption(key, val) {
    if(!options[key]) {
      options[key] = val;
    }

    //It already exists? Handle it somehow
  };

  return {
    getOption: getOption,
    setOption: setOption
  };
}();

var debuggerProto = function() {
  var level = 'DEBUG';

  var getLevel = function getLevel() {
    return level;
  };

  var setLevel = function setLevel(_level) {
    level = _level;
  };

  return {
    getLevel: getLevel,
    setLevel: setLevel
  };
}();


var mixedUpStoreProto = _.extend({}, optionsProto, debuggerProto);

var store = Object.create(mixedUpStoreProto);

store.setLevel('INFO');
store.getLevel(); //INFO

store.addOption('somekey', 'someval');
store.getOption('somekey'); // someval
```

This way you can compose a lot of objects by reusing the proto's.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to @Epsil0neR and @gor181 for answers but is possible than I don´t do question correctly.
Actually I ask again on Ramda Github issue because I need implement the API with curry functions. 
Finally, many hours late I go`it .

Here is the code, maybe is useful for somebody: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1291

```
//return 'fn' with all 'obj' props
function functionize(obj, fn)
{
    let fn = fn;
    for( let i in obj ){ fn[i] = obj[i] };
    return fn;
}


SubStore = function(options) {
    this.options = options;
}
SubStore.prototype.getOptions = function() { return this.options }
SubStore.prototype.setOptions = function(options) { this.options = options }
SubStore.prototype.insert = function(doc) { return doc }
SubStore.prototype.find = function(selector, options) { return selector }

SubStore.create = function(options) {
    let sub = functionize(new SubStore(options), R.curry(function (args, fn) {
        let self = sub;         //reference to new SubStore obj
        return self[fn](args);
    }))
    return sub;
}

Store = function(options) {
    this.options = options;
}
Store.prototype.insert = function(args) {
    for (let i = 0, len = args.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ( R.is(Function, args[i]) ) { args[i] = args[i]('insert') }
        console.log(args[i]);
    }
}
Store.prototype.find = function(args) {
    for (let i = 0, len = args.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ( R.is(Function, args[i]) ) { args[i] = args[i]('find') }
        console.log(args[i]);
    }
}
```

Test code

```
store = new Store();

sub1 = SubStore.create({path:'perfil'});
sub2 = SubStore.create({path:'rol'});

// test#1
store.insert([ sub1({name: "Foo"}), sub2({age: 18}) ]);

// test#2
store.insert([ sub1.insert({name: "Foo"}), sub2.insert({age: 18}) ]);
```

Is you need a `Javascript ES5`version just replace `let` with `var` and you must add `Ramda` library too for curry function.

Thanks