# Constructing object to have a constructor method containing a set property method

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to make an object as a mock to pass into a test.

I don't know if I'm constructing it correctly - I'm getting `Error: User() method does not exist`.

```
    injectedUser = { 
        set: function(key, val){ 
            this[key] = val;
        }
    };

    injectedParse = {
        Parse: {
            User: function() { 
                return injectedUser;
            }
        }
    };


    Parse = function() { 
        return injectedParse;
    };
```

The desired behavior I'm looking for is for function `Parse.User` to be called with `user = new Parse.User` and be able to do `user.set("key", "value");`

But it seems like I'm not building this object properly? I have another issue but since it is more a javascript thing potentially, I made a new, more general issue about building objects

I also tried 
                set = function (key, val) {
                this[key] = val;
            }

```
        mockParse = function(){
            this.User()
        };
        mockParse.prototype.User = function(){
            return set
        };

        $provide.value('Parse', mockParse);
```

That gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

All the information you should know about constructing objects are at: http://ericleads.com/2013/02/fluent-javascript-three-different-kinds-of-prototypal-oo/

Comment: Any idea what the problem is? I tried another version, got the same results. details in question

Comment: What you want is to mix prototypes in. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510045/javascript-function-acting-like-object-and-function/31510759#31510759 for an example.